# Object method attaching function to .hover returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I am trying to add themes to a webpage. I am doing this by creating an object constructor, and creating individual theme objects. For this particular theme, every time a tab is hovered over, it should change to be a random color, and then when hovered out of, change to a different color.

The object seems to be constructing properly, and the random color function outputs a string viable for applying using $('someElement').css(), but for some reason it seems that when I try to wrap it all together in a .on("hover, ...) it just doesn't work. When myThemeObject.method() should bind a tab to a .hover function, the console returns undefined as if it isn't entering the function.

The part I think is failing is the fourth main block of code.

```
// The theme constructor lets each theme define some stuff on the page.
//Type constructor: "Name", "<link href='someFont'>", true, 16%,
function Theme( name, selectValue, fontLink, showSidebar, sideBarDistance, marginDistance, bgImage, bgTint ){
    this.name = name;
    this.value = selectValue; //from actual select
    this.link = fontLink;
    this.margin = marginDistance; //px value
    this.showSidebar = showSidebar; // boolean
    this.sideBarDistance = sideBarDistance;
    this.backgroundImage = bgImage;
    this.backgroundTint = bgTint; //rgba
    }


// Construct our object
var someTheme = new Theme(
    "themeName",
    "themeSelectValue", //Themes are picked in a select
    " <link href='You get the idea' ",
    10,
    true,
    "default",
    "linkURL"
    );


// Generates rgba colors in a string, but a value is a parameter:
// --> "rgba(231,23,4, x)"
function generateRandomRGBA(aValue){
    var aString = String(aValue);
    var r = Math.random()*256|0;
    var g = Math.random()*256|0;
    var b = Math.random()*256|0;
    var x = String(r);
    var y = String(g);
    var z = String(b);
    var q = ", ";  //Probably Don't need space in this.
    return "rgba("+x+q+y+q+z+q+aString+")";
    }


// Defines the method.
// headerRandomize is passed a boolean to set or unset the randomizing
// if set is true, then the tabs are given a .hover function that will call
// generateRandomRGBA. otherwise, .off should unset it.
someTheme.headerRandomize = function (set){
//Set is a boolean
    //We are going to randomize the main tabs and sub tabs of the header
    var $submenuTabs = $('.dd-submenu-tab');
    var $tabs = $('.dd-menu-tab');
    //unset
    if (set != true) {
        console.log("set is false.");
        $tabs.off("hover");
        $submenuTabs.off("hover");
    } else {
    // otherwise set. set parameter to a value of color
        console.log("set is not false.");
        // Console logged this ^
        $tabs.on( "hover" , function(){
            console.log("We got this far.");
            //Console never logged that ^
            var color = generateRandomRBGA(.65);
            console.log(color);
            this.css('background-color', color );
        });
        $submenuTabs.on( "hover" , function(){
            var color = generateRandomRBGA( .65);
            console.log(color);
            this.css('background-color', color );
        });
    }
};
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was wrong, but this fixed it:

```
function randomizeSubtabs (set) {
    //We are going to randomize the tabs and dd-submenu tabs.
    var $subTabs = $('.dd-submenu-tab');
    //unset
    if (set != true) {
        $subTabs.off("hover");
    } else {
    // otherwise set. set parameter to a value of color
        $subTabs.hover (function(){
            var color = generateRandomRGBA(0.65); //0.4 is A value.
            $(this).css('background-color', color );
        });
        $subTabs.mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(255,255,255,0.85)' );
        });
    }
};
```

and then I'd call it in the console and that fixed the problem. I for some reason, trying to use the function as a method just wasn't working. I think I'm just going to try and link the function to an object property value, or maybe not at all. Anyway, thanks all.